Is there a way to add format to a particular cell or a column of cells in jxls template?
I am trying to generate an excel report which requires the flight hours of flight trip to be displayed under a column called "FlightHours". I am using a JXLS template to generate the report. So I need the values in the above column to be of the format "[h]:mm" so that when the report is generated and the user selects the few cells , the sum of the selected values(here the time is displayed at the bottom right corner of the excel sheet.

I tried adding jx:each(items="reports" var="report" lastCell="N2"  formatCells="[h]:mm:C1") as the comment for the cell to achieve it, but it did not work.
